# Hibernate, InteliJ - generate persistence mapping, incorrect table name

Tags: java, sql-server, hibernate, azure, intellij-idea

I am using hibernate with InteliJ Idea ultimate, every time I try to Generate Persistence mapping of my tables, it generates them with slightly incorrect @Table name

[My database structure - IMGUR IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XSGQe.png)

so my correct table name for "Activity" table would be: "[dbo].[Activity]"

but InteliJ generates it like this:

```
@Table(name = "Modules", schema = "dbo", catalog = "test-V4ClientDb")
```

And it causes errors where it can not retrieve data:

> ERROR: Incorrect syntax near '-'.
>   org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract
>   ResultSet
>           at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:106)
>           at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:42)
>           at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:111)
>           at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:97)
>           at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:79)
>           at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.getResultSet(AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:434)
>           at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.executeQueryStatement(AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:186)
>           at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.executeLoad(AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:121)
>           at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.executeLoad(AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:86)
>           at org.hibernate.loader.entity.plan.AbstractLoadPlanBasedEntityLoader.load(AbstractLoadPlanBasedEntityLoader.java:167)
>           at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.load(AbstractEntityPersister.java:4004)
>           at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.loadFromDatasource(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:508)
>           at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.doLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:478)
>           at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.load(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:219)
>           at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.proxyOrLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:278)
>           at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.doOnLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:121)
>           at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.onLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:89)
>           at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireLoad(SessionImpl.java:1220)
>           at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.access$1900(SessionImpl.java:203)
>           at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl$IdentifierLoadAccessImpl.doLoad(SessionImpl.java:2767)
>           at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl$IdentifierLoadAccessImpl.load(SessionImpl.java:2741)
>           at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.get(SessionImpl.java:1056)
>           at hibernate.DatabaseManager.retrieveModuleFromDatabase(DatabaseManager.java:82)
>           at hibernate.DatabaseManager.populateDatabase(DatabaseManager.java:58)
>           at runner.TestRunner.setUp(TestRunner.java:30)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>           at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
>           at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
>           at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
>           at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:24)
>           at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
>           at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
>           at cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber.run(Cucumber.java:100)
>           at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
>           at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:115)
>           at org.testng.junit.JUnit4TestRunner.start(JUnit4TestRunner.java:81)
>           at org.testng.junit.JUnit4TestRunner.run(JUnit4TestRunner.java:69)
>           at org.testng.TestRunner$1.run(TestRunner.java:697)
>           at org.testng.TestRunner.runJUnitWorkers(TestRunner.java:1004)
>           at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRunJUnit(TestRunner.java:728)
>           at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:629)
>           at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:366)
>           at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:361)
>           at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:319)
>           at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:268)
>           at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
>           at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
>           at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1244)
>           at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1169)
>           at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1064)
>           at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGExecutor.run(TestNGExecutor.java:135)
>           at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGDirectoryTestSuite.executeSingleClass(TestNGDirectoryTestSuite.java:112)
>           at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGDirectoryTestSuite.execute(TestNGDirectoryTestSuite.java:99)
>           at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGProvider.invoke(TestNGProvider.java:146)
>           at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.invokeProviderInSameClassLoader(ForkedBooter.java:383)
>           at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:344)
>           at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.execute(ForkedBooter.java:125)
>           at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:417)
>   Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Incorrect
>   syntax near '-'.
>           at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDatabaseError(SQLServerException.java:254)
>           at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.getNextResult(SQLServerStatement.java:1608)
>           at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.doExecutePreparedStatement(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:578)
>           at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement$PrepStmtExecCmd.doExecute(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:508)
>           at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.execute(IOBuffer.java:7240)
>           at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.executeCommand(SQLServerConnection.java:2869)
>           at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeCommand(SQLServerStatement.java:243)
>           at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeStatement(SQLServerStatement.java:218)
>           at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.executeQuery(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:434)
>           at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:70)
>           ... 56 more

is there a possibility to configure InteliJ to use correct naming?

I am using Microsoft Azure sql server.

Thank you.

**EDIT**

It also works if there is no "catalog" specified

```
@Table(name = "Modules", schema = "dbo")
```

So question still is, how to configure InteliJ hibernate tool to use correct naming.

Comment: Could you add information about the error you get?

Comment: Hello Andrey, I have edited my post and added full error log, thank you.

Comment: I do not think there is a separate option for this. Feel free to vote/follow the [IDEA-200824](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-200824) request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you cannot use the caracter "-" in your catalog string.